# Infor PM Application Studio

Tags: olap

Is there anyone here using Infor PM Application studio or has experience with it? I m stuck on afew problems but find virtually no resource to get help and the manual is dull and not helpful.

Please let me know if you can answer afew question. I'm new to the application so most questions are usability, things like how to manipulate global variables.

Specifically, my question is to do with How i can relate a Selection in "List box" to a HyperBlock.

for example, if i have a List Box that allows user to select a year (2010,2011...etc). This list box outputs to a global variable I’ve created, and i can use this global variable to structure the Hyperblock to show the contents based on selected year.

BUT  i also need to structure hyperblock based on previous year and the year before that and not just current. So if user picks 2011, i also need to display 2010 and 2009. I am stuck on how i can do this.

Thanks

Comment: If you have a question, post that question _if_ it's on topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you use the global variable in the Structure Selection of the List which fills the HyperBlock. To be able to answer your question I need to know more about the case. 
Do you use Client or Server Olap List?
Does the combo offer a flat or a hierarchical list of elements?
Do you always want to take the years from the first to the selected one?

In case you have a flat list of years and want to select all from the first till the selected one, just create a range in the Structure Selection. The range should go from the first year to the variable stored in the global List.

Regards

Kris

Answer (score 1):

yes, there are developers using Infor PM10 App Studio. Feel free to ask more questions to me or the comunity as StackOverflow will solve them all ;-)

Here is another solution to your problem with scripting (where "ListViewYear" is the Name of your Year Dropdown box and "glb_YearFrom" hast to be a global variable):

```
Sub ListViewYear_SelChange ()  
  year = LV_Year.Text     ' e.g. "2011"
  SetGlobalVariable "glb_YearFrom", year-2
End Sub
```

The global Var "glb_YearFrom" can now be used in any Hyperblock List to filter it's content.